# how to use a LSTM model after training it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I'm new to tensorflow and I'm using [LSTM for Predicting stock prices](https://medium.com/@fglancszpigel/basic-lstm-model-for-predicting-stock-prices-python-2bf6ba470e85) to learn to use LSTM for predicting stock market prices.
The question is: After training the model and saving it, how should I actually use it to predict the future of the market? I mean what should be the input for the `predict` method?

Comment: exactly the type of data you used for `fit`

Comment: @DavidS I understand. the data is a series of "closing price" of each day in the market. for example if it were a model for recognizing a cat, I would use a new cat image for the `predict()`. but for this kind of prediction, what should I use?

Comment: The same type of input what you have passed as train_x parameter of the fit() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will base my answer on your comment:

> the data is a series of "closing price" of each day in the market. for
> example if it were a model for recognizing a cat, I would use a new
> cat image for the predict(). but for this kind of prediction, what
> should I use?

Generally speaking, when you train a model you should use the same type of data (type and context).

Given the example of the cat, it true that you will test it on images of cats, but it might not work good on tigers/pumas/etc.

---

*So if your training data, stock market, came from a specific place (say Asia) so you should test your model on data collected from Asia.*

Comment: I understand sir. I have trouble finding the format of data to provide to the `predict` method. and as I see its not as simple as giving a cat image! I need to understand the test_data format of that tutorial well first.
thanks for your answer

Comment: @Juggernaut In the tutorial, they use the Apple stock downloaded from YahooFinance. So they wanted to predict Apple in particular. You can download any stock (they use only 1) and train the model from scratch using their approach for start.